# After Plugins Update Wordpress doesn't load everything from uploads folder

Tags: wordpress, general-network-error

I'm having a huge problem with this site http://www.oktoberfest.it

After a massive plugins update (9 updates) this website is returning this error:

> NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

on all images in the "uploads" folder and this error:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found

on js files from wp-includes folder. Even jQuery won't load.

Here what I have done so far:

- Disabled All Plugins
- Reset Plugins Folder Via FTP
- Update Manually Wordpress to 3.5.1
- Reset uploads folder permissions (from Aruba control panel)
- Set uploads folder permissions to 777
- Delete all unused plugins
- Check Aruba log file and find that the "Option Indexes not allowed here" error shows up every page load
- Check .htaccess file but it's ok

After the plugin update wordpress won't display any upgrade but It had to beacuse I was running on v.3.4.2.

If I try to paste a image link on the browser I receve the "Internal Server Error" page.

If I try to edit a post, all the images are marked as broken and if I try to load a new image it uploads it but can't show me any preview or the image itself.

If I try to start a plugin installation or a wordpress update the page stucks on the downloading, but the plugin or the system is updated.

Comment: Probably you don't have a backup, do you? See if [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) dumps any useful info. Any Javascript errors in the browser console? Revise all this [troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) steps.

Comment: I do not have a backup unfortunately. :(
The errors I've posted above are from the JS console. I will try to see if your two links resolve this problem.

Comment: Nothing, also following all troubleshooting the problem hasn't resolved. :(

Comment: The site is trying to load jQuery 1.6.1 and that doesn't exist. WP doesn't put version number in the jQuery file name. This is the theme or some plugin fault. Backup the DB and try to downgrade WP to 3.4.2.

Comment: The problem was there also with WP 3.4.2. Seems that the site has some problems in finding some paths. Via FTP the uploads path and wp-includes are still there. like before. But maybe worth a try the downgrading. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've resolved! Aruba was telling me this error:

```
/web/htdocs/www.oktoberfest.it/home/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess: Option Indexes not allowed here
```

I've simply deleted the .htaccess file from the uploads folder and all gone ok! I don't know what's happened in this particular site because all my other sites have this file without problems.

the file was containing only this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

like other sites. It's a mistery. Thanks to everyone anyway!

Comment: This happened to a site I manage after an admin removed a plugin...The site was up but all the images were gone.  I just removed the .htaccess file in the uploads directory and the images came back.